# List is not updating in fragment viewpager android

Tags: java, android

I have an activity, inside of that activity I have a viewpager which is holding four fragments. In each fragment there is a custom listview and when I try to update the list and do notifyDataSetChanged() it does not change or update list on the screen. Next time it manipulate next list member. Any help guys how to solve it.
**Here is my fragment class where I try to update list in onpostdelete method**

public class StreamFragment extends Fragment implements Constants, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, ItemInterface {

```
private static final String STATE_LIST = "State Adapter Data";

private static final int PROFILE_NEW_POST = 4;

Spinner mNavSpinner;

ListView mListView;
TextView mMessage;
ImageView mSplash;

SwipeRefreshLayout mItemsContainer;

FloatingActionButton mFabButton;

private ArrayList<Item> itemsList;
private StreamListAdapter itemsAdapter;
private String uniID;
private int category = 0;
private int itemId = 0;
private int arrayLength = 0;
private Boolean loadingMore = false;
private Boolean viewMore = false;
private Boolean restore = false;

public StreamFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        itemsList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_LIST);
        itemsAdapter = new StreamListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList, this);

        restore = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("restore");
        itemId = savedInstanceState.getInt("itemId");
        category = savedInstanceState.getInt("category");

    } else {

        itemsList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        itemsAdapter = new StreamListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList, this);

        restore = false;
        itemId = 0;
        category = 0;
    }

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle!=null)
    category = bundle.getInt("category", 0);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stream, container, false);

    mItemsContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container_items);
    mItemsContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    mMessage = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.message);
    mSplash = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.splash);

    mFabButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
    mFabButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new);

    mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    SharedPreferences preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String uniname=preferences.getString("Uni","");
    uniID = preferences.getString("UniID","");
    mFabButton.attachToListView(mListView, new ScrollDirectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollDown() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollUp() {

        }

    }, new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore) && (viewMore) && !(mItemsContainer.isRefreshing())) {

                if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

                    loadingMore = true;

                    getItems();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mListView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    mFabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewItemActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, STREAM_NEW_POST);
        }
    });

    if (itemsAdapter.getCount() == 0) {

        showMessage(getText(R.string.label_empty_list).toString());

    } else {

        hideMessage();
    }

    if (!restore) {

        showMessage(getText(R.string.msg_loading_2).toString());

        getItems();
    }

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putBoolean("restore", true);
    outState.putInt("itemId", itemId);
    outState.putInt("category", category);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(STATE_LIST, itemsList);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

        itemId = 0;
        getItems();

    } else {

        mItemsContainer.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == STREAM_NEW_POST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        itemId = 0;
        getItems();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

public void getItems() {

    mItemsContainer.setRefreshing(true);

    CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_STREAM_GET, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    if (!loadingMore) {

                        itemsList.clear();
                    }

                    try {

                        arrayLength = 0;

                        if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {

                            itemId = response.getInt("itemId");

                            if (response.has("items")) {

                                JSONArray itemsArray = response.getJSONArray("items");

                                arrayLength = itemsArray.length();

                                if (arrayLength > 0) {

                                    for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {

                                        JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject) itemsArray.get(i);

                                        Item item = new Item(itemObj);

                                        itemsList.add(item);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } finally {

                        loadingComplete();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            loadingComplete();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("accountId", Long.toString(App.getInstance().getId()));
            params.put("accessToken", App.getInstance().getAccessToken());
            params.put("itemId", Integer.toString(itemId));
            params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);
            //params.put("category", Integer.toString(category));
            params.put("universityId",uniID );
            // params.put("category", uniID);
            params.put("language", "en");

            return params;

        }
    };

    App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
}

public void loadingComplete() {

    if (arrayLength == LIST_ITEMS) {

        viewMore = true;

    } else {

        viewMore = false;
    }

    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (itemsAdapter.getCount() == 0) {

        if (StreamFragment.this.isVisible()) {

            showMessage(getText(R.string.label_empty_list).toString());
        }

    } else {

        hideMessage();
    }

    loadingMore = false;
    mItemsContainer.setRefreshing(false);
}

public void onCategoryChange(int cat) {

    itemId = 0;

    getItems();

    category = cat;
}

public void report(int position) {

    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

    PostReportDialog alert = new PostReportDialog();

    Bundle b  = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("position", position);
    b.putInt("reason", 0);

    alert.setArguments(b);
    alert.show(fm, "alert_dialog_post_report");
}

public void onPostReport(int position, int reasonId) {

    final Item item = itemsList.get(position);

    if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

        Api api = new Api(getActivity());

        api.postReport(item.getId(), reasonId);

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getText(R.string.msg_network_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void remove(int position) {

    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

    PostDeleteDialog alert = new PostDeleteDialog();

    Bundle b  = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("position", position);

    alert.setArguments(b);
    alert.show(fm, "alert_dialog_post_delete");
}

public void onPostDelete(int position) {

    final Item item = itemsList.get(position);

    itemsList.remove(position);
    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (mListView.getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {

        showMessage(getText(R.string.label_empty_list).toString());

    } else {

        hideMessage();
    }

    if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

        Api api = new Api(getActivity());

        api.postDelete(item.getId());

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getText(R.string.msg_network_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void onPostRemove(final int position) {

    /** Getting the fragment manager */
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

    /** Instantiating the DialogFragment class */
    PostDeleteDialog alert = new PostDeleteDialog();

    /** Creating a bundle object to store the selected item's index */
    Bundle b  = new Bundle();

    /** Storing the selected item's index in the bundle object */
    b.putInt("position", position);

    /** Setting the bundle object to the dialog fragment object */
    alert.setArguments(b);

    /** Creating the dialog fragment object, which will in turn open the alert dialog window */

    alert.show(fm, "alert_dialog_post_delete");
}

public void onPostShare(final int position) {

    final Item item = itemsList.get(position);

    Api api = new Api(getActivity());
    api.postShare(item);
}

public void action(int position) {

    final Item item = itemsList.get(position);

    if (item.getFromUserId() == App.getInstance().getId()) {

        /** Getting the fragment manager */
        android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

        /** Instantiating the DialogFragment class */
        MyPostActionDialog alert = new MyPostActionDialog();

        /** Creating a bundle object to store the selected item's index */
        Bundle b  = new Bundle();

        /** Storing the selected item's index in the bundle object */
        b.putInt("position", position);

        /** Setting the bundle object to the dialog fragment object */
        alert.setArguments(b);

        /** Creating the dialog fragment object, which will in turn open the alert dialog window */

        alert.show(fm, "alert_my_post_action");

    } else {

        /** Getting the fragment manager */
        android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

        /** Instantiating the DialogFragment class */
        PostActionDialog alert = new PostActionDialog();

        /** Creating a bundle object to store the selected item's index */
        Bundle b  = new Bundle();

        /** Storing the selected item's index in the bundle object */
        b.putInt("position", position);

        /** Setting the bundle object to the dialog fragment object */
        alert.setArguments(b);

        /** Creating the dialog fragment object, which will in turn open the alert dialog window */

        alert.show(fm, "alert_post_action");
    }
}

public void showMessage(String message) {

    mMessage.setText(message);
    mMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mSplash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void hideMessage() {

    mMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mSplash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void onPostCreateChat(int position) {

    final Item item = itemsList.get(position);

    createChat(item.getFromUserId());
}

public void onPostFollow(int position) {

    final Item item = itemsList.get(position);

    Api api = new Api(getActivity());

    api.profileFollow(item.getFromUserId());
}

public void createChat(final long profileId) {

    if (App.getInstance().isConnected() && App.getInstance().getId() != 0) {

        CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_CHAT_NEW, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {

                            if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChatActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("position", 0);
                                intent.putExtra("chatId", response.getInt("id"));
                                intent.putExtra("profileId", response.getLong("withUserId"));
                                intent.putExtra("chatTitle", response.getString("title"));

                                intent.putExtra("fromUserId", response.getLong("fromUserId"));
                                intent.putExtra("toUserId", response.getLong("toUserId"));

                                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.msg_chat_create_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_data_loading), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("accountId", Long.toString(App.getInstance().getId()));
                params.put("accessToken", App.getInstance().getAccessToken());

                params.put("profileId", Long.toString(profileId));

                return params;
            }
        };

        int socketTimeout = 0;//0 seconds - change to what you want
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        jsonReq.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
  }
```

Comment: First of all I'll suggest you to use RecyclerView instead of ListView. Second, please post some code, can't help without it.

Comment: It is old code and there is too much that's why didnt post it. i thought it will be hard to read that much code. But ill post it.

Comment: Can't figure out the error like this bro. At least post adapter class and method where you are adding new data.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

In **Activity**:

```
BaseFragment visibleFragment = getViewPager().getItem(getPageAdapter.getCurrentItem());
```

**BaseFragment** should extend Fragment, and have a method called **updateList()**.

```
visibleFragment.updateList();

// visibleFragment is the fragment visible to the user
```

Inside the **BaseFragment**:

```
public void updateList(){
   // fragment has a ListView - listview
   // and an Adapter for the list - adapter
   // add, remove, move, items in adapter
   // and call notifyDataSetChanged();
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```